# Using with() results in subsequent queries in Laravel 9

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

Assume I have the follow `hasMany()` models:

```
Country > State > City > Street > Person
```

And I want to retrieve person "John", but also know what country he belongs to:

```
$person = Person::with(['country'], ['state'], ['city'], ['street'],
['person'] = function ($query) {
     $query->where('name', '=', 'John')
});
```

This generates a separate query for each model which does not seem efficient. Should I use join instead?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with MySQL 8+, there is not much difference, and I wouldn't use joins.
You can also use this package for nested relations
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep